# How to add link to XML file?

Tags: ios, xml

I have a UITable which is filled up with XML data - bookname, author and link of it's PDF. First i need to create an XML file I have written the code as below but it is showing link as a text only. I want a link on it's place. Please guide me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<books>
<book>
    <bookname>Book1</bookname><author>ABC</author><link>http://api.geonames.org/neighbours</link>
</book>

...
...

</books>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean it's showing link as text only ? How do you show it exactly?

Comment: I have uploaded my simulator screen shot for this. Link is not displaying as a link I mean it is just a simple text. I want to navigate from it.

Comment: Just change the property of the text. Use `NSAttributedString`. Yo can then add color, stroke... For managing the link, since it's a UITableView, just look at the method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. When it's called, you can do whatever you want according to the cell selected, like opening a URL into a UIWebView or redirect to Safari for example.

Comment: Did u set link text on label or on textview?

Comment: but i want that particular line to work as link works with html & not on didSelect method. Is it possible or not?

Comment: XML will return it as simple or plain text. You will have to decode the attribute <link> and then make change the text attribute as detailed by @Larme.

On the tap call tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

If you add the text to a Text View

UITextView has the property dataDetectorTypes to show the the link as highlighted real link.

@property(nonatomic) UIDataDetectorTypes dataDetectorTypes
Set dataDetectorTypes with UIDataDetectorTypeLink.

Use it as below

        myTextView.editable = NO;
        myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;

Comment: @PiyushPatel I am displaying it in cell.detailTextLabel

Comment: Try using TextView

UITextView *test = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 150.0f, 320.0f, 200.0f)];
        test.text = @"Some text http://www.yahoo.com/ more text";
        test.editable = NO;
        test.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
        [self addSubview:test];

Comment: you want to open link in web view or safari ?

Comment: @PiyushPatel want to open link in webview

Comment: if you want to set clickable text link you may use UITextView for that and if u want to continue with it as you have done above then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.urlink.com"]];` method for that.

Comment: @gurmandeep your suggestion worked man! Thank you so much :) but it is opening in safari.. anyways i will manage it somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome @KrutikaSonawala

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use link as usual web link in this case you should look at `NSLinkAttributeName`.

Example:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Link to site!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: "https://www.google.com", range: NSMakeRange(0, 4))
```